# Setting cell border width in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, border

Although cell borders in a GoogleSpreadsheet can be set manually to 6 different styles (dotted, dashed, solid (1px width), solid (2px width), solid (3px width) and double), it seems the current version of the API is limited to the options DOTTED, DASHED and SOLID for [BorderStyle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/border-style). The latter has a 1px width.

Is there a way which allows me to set a border with 2px width, either by choosing one of the other 3 styles not in the BorderStyle enum, or by setting the border width by any workarounds?

**Update**: (revisiting this a few years later) - there are now other options for BorderStyle, including SOLID_MEDIUM which I was originally looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that multiple border thickness options is a very new feature as of February 2017, so I don't think it has made its way into the Enum options of apps script.

[Google Help Forum Post on add border style options](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/RLQCPw3wr3w/d5BuG_9gBwAJ)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I guess it means, it will appear in the Enum sooner or later. Any idea about how long it typically takes for such a feature to get implemented in the language?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, but the help forums and the documentation site are the best resource that I know of for keeping up with what is current or deprecated.

Comment: Revisiting my old post: SOLID_MEDIUM, SOLID_THICK and DOUBLE are now all available in the BorderStyle enum.

Comment: I can't make border style or width work on any settings. All I get is blank borders if I set borders at all so it is obviously having soem effect, just not the right one.

Comment: @markhorrocks See my answer below - does that work for you or are you running into the same problem?

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
function borders() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Line 1").getRange("E21:F26").setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, 'black', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);
}
```

Of course the sheet and range are just what I used for testing, should work with any range/sheet.

[Here's the documentation for the border styles](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/border-style) and [here is the documentation for .setBorder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBorder(Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,String,BorderStyle))

Comment: I should have mentioned I was using the ruby api but I did set border-style to SOLID and SOLID_MEDIUM, with and without border-width.,

Comment: @markhorrocks Are you saying then that the line of code I provided is not working for you? And just to clarify when you're setting the border-style, you're doing it like `SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID` correct? Also the border width is taken care of in that statement -  the one I just typed out is 1 px `SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM` is 2 px, and `SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK` is 3px.

Comment: @markhorrocks You should have asked a new question with your code instead of offering bounty on a resolved question on a different language. The enums doesn't seem to be a problem. The issue must be somewhere else in your code.